# How can I draw ItemDecoration correctly when RecyclerView element is animating its height?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that uses a LinearLayoutManager (vertical). What I am trying to accomplish is having the item decoration (full width and 1px tall) divider animate with the view when the view is moved (the translationY() deals with that properly) and when the view changes its height. In the current code that I have below, the divider will jump to the future position of the bottom of the view rather than the current bottom during the animation. Is there any way I can account for the height changes in the item decoration during the animation to make the animation look better?

I am changing the view height by using notifyItemChanged() on the adapter for the RecyclerView.

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable mDivider;

    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
        mDivider = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_divider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int right = parent.getWidth();
        int dividerHeight = mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            View nextChild = parent.getChildAt(i + 1);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams1 =
                    (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams2 =
                    (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) nextChild.getLayoutParams();
            int left = 0;
            if (layoutParams1 != null && layoutParams2 != null) {
                left = Math.min(layoutParams1.leftMargin, layoutParams2.leftMargin);
            }

            int ty = (int) (child.getTranslationY() + 0.5f);
            int top = child.getBottom() + ty;
            int bottom = top + dividerHeight;

            mDivider.setBounds(
                    left,
                    top,
                    right,
                    bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this just something that is not possible in the item decoration api?

Comment: so...the normal animations (add, remove) will animate the decoration correctly, but when changing the views `height` it will just jump? if so, could you provide the code from changing the views height? do you animate the view height change? FYI, the decoration itself looks alright.

Comment: The height is being changed automatically by the default recyclerview animator (by having a view inside be set to GONE)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Solved this one by adding child's transition to calculations in the onDraw method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        //Here is the trick!
        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin  + Math.round(child.getTranslationY());
        int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As new inserted cells show with alpha animation in my case, I added: mDivider.setAlpha((int)(255.0 * child.getAlpha())); before drawing to show divider with the same animation.